# How to insert icons in select list in VueJS?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, frontend

I want to insert country icons near the name of each of the countries in the selection drop-down menu. I have a folder with these icons and the path should be specified to this folder.

Here is code:

```
           <select v-model="defCountry">
            <option
              v-for="item in countries"
              :selected="item.def"
              :key="item.key"
              :value="{key: item.key, val: item.val, def: item.def}"
            >
              {{item.val}}
            </option>
          </select>
```

Also, it is important to clarify that the `key` field matches the file name, so it would be nice to automate this. I mean, if the file name, for example, `ZW.svg` matches the `key` with name `ZW`, then this file should be put as an icon.

How can I implement this?

Thanks for answers!

Comment: I doubt you would able to achieve that with html select

Comment: This doesn't directly answer your question, but it might help in some cases: consider all the html symbols, like an umbrella (```&#9730;```) and put that alongside or in place of any text in the option tags. This is a good source for html symbols: https://www.toptal.com/designers/htmlarrows/symbols/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add the image tag before the country name this way (change the path to the images according to your project). But you have to add some library to change from native select to a custom one, or use a flag icon font to achieve that, as Bharat says in his comment.

```html
<select v-model="defCountry">
  <option
    v-for="item in countries"
    :selected="item.def"
    :key="item.key"
    :value="{key: item.key, val: item.val, def: item.def}"
  >
    <img src="../assets/images/flags/{{item.key}}.svg" /> {{item.val}}
  </option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

Directly using the basic select, all we can do is use a font like font awesome and add an icon. Otherwise you need custom dropdown (menu like). An example is here which used el-select

https://jsfiddle.net/budgw/L4y8zw1e/36/

```js
select {
  font-family: 'FontAwesome'
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://pro.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.10.0/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-AYmEC3Yw5cVb3ZcuHtOA93w35dYTsvhLPVnYs9eStHfGJvOvKxVfELGroGkvsg+p" crossorigin="anonymous"/>


<label>Font Awesome</label>
<select class="fa">
  <option value="">Select</option>
  <option class="fa">&#xf2b9 Some text </option>
  <option class="fa"> &#xf30b Some text  </option>
  <option class="fa">&#xf0f3 Some text  </option>
  <option class="fa">&#xf273 Some text  </option>
</select>
```